# How to use copy_to_user in workqueue (linux, kernel)?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to defer work to a workqueue and by this make use of my multiple processor cores. Also I would like to copy data back to a user space buffer after the work is done. Now I know that a user space address is also dependent on the user space process. I already pass `current` to the work function. How can I set up the right context in work function so I can safely use `copy_to_user` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy_to_user` intented to be called from user context only. It is bad idea to call it from workqueue context.

You can allocate memory block (kmalloc), submit it to workqueue, wait until wokqueue finished it's work in user context (in functions like read, write, ioctl) and copy workqueue result to userspace.

As an another approach you can allocate kernel memory and mmap it to userspace so the memory could be directly accessed by kernel and userspace at same time. Each time workqueue update kernel memory the data became available to userspace. You have to implement some sort of synchronization between userspace and kernel space workqueues to make this approach workable.

See [uvc_queue.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvc_queue.c) for example of mmap implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case I want to stack file systems. So e.g. I get  read-request with a buffer (user space). Now I allocate kernel memory (kmalloc) and read from sub-filesystems (use kernel_read in workqueue) to my kernel buffer. Now if I only copy to the user space buffer after all work is done I can not parallelize the copying -which I hope to be faster. I am limited to read and write calls from user space of the topmost file system, so I think I cannot use mmap.

Comment: @tofi, I doubt what parallel copying using multiply cores will be faster than single core copy. Small block (the one what fit CORE internal cache) no sense to copy using many cores. Large blocks copy bottlenecked by external RAM speed. Single core write runs much faster than RAM. You can benchmark that using kernel memory only. If you find significant improvement in speed, than that make sense to work on.